# PDO - Changing old mysql_fetch_object

Tags: mysql, pdo

I have a small problem by using PDO instead of `mysql_fetch_object`.

I tried to find something to replace it but nothing seems to work.

First my link is done :

```
$link = new PDO('mysql:host='.$local.';dbname='.$nomBase.'', $user, $password, $pdo_options);
```

Here is my code :

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)){
$data1=$row->nickname;
$data2=$row->id_contact;
echo ("<option ");
if ($handled==$data2) { echo ("selected "); }
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should change it to :

```
while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)){
...
}
```

You will find more information about it here : [PDOStatement Fetch](http://php.net/manual/fr/pdostatement.fetch.php)

It is a good choice to change for PDO ! Need more people like you ;).